# Creating a Settings Page in a (sorta) Offline Chrome App

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

So, I'm pretty new to coding in general, but I've been messing around with an open-source browser that runs in a chrome app. So far, I've been able to add some cool stuff, but I really want to be able to change the default search engine. Now I know how to change the entire browser's search engine, but finding a way to change variables and make it stick even after the app is restarted has been an issue for me. Here's my code right now:

```
switch(searchEngine){
  default:
      // Return a DuckDuckGo search
      return 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + text+'&kh=d&kp=-1&kz=1&kf=fw&k1=-1';
  break;
  case 'duckduckgo':
    return 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + text+'&kh=d&kp=-1&kz=1&kf=fw&k1=-1';
  break;
  case 'bing':
    return 'https://www.bing.com/search?q='+text;
    break;
  case 'google':
    return 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+text;
     break;
}
```

And then I've got another html file that I need to have an interface - preferably a dropdown selection menu - that can change searchEngine to the necessary string to trigger the switch. The other thing I need to happen with it is to have the choice be persistent between startups of the app. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!